# Ruby on Rails3: how can I prevent numeric values to be converted to String in ActiveRecord (to_i and to_f are too slow)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.0.3, ruby 1.8.7, PostgreSQL 9.1.9 from standard repository of my Debian stable (6.0.7). I'm creating a report by fetching the data for a month, joining multiple tables using "joins" and then parsing all that data. The data types are string, integer and float. I'm aggregating the SQL request so some fields are generated using count(). When I'm parsing all this data in the controller I need to call to_i and to_f to all the numeric fields. The report is taking few minutes to generate. The SQL part is just a couple of seconds, all the rest is parsing the data. I noticed that the biggest time consumer is the part of the code where I convert every numeric field from String to appropriate numeric type (using either to_i or to_f). Is there any way to keep the original numeric types of the values?

I have read about improvements of ruby 1.9 over 1.8 so I went and deployed ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) in order to see if the parsing will get faster but sadly, it did not.

I understand if it's not possible to do so for a calculated values, e. g. when uging SQL count(), but maybe at least for the static values it is possible?

Here are the related code parts: http://pastebin.com/index/tzWsQZtz

Any recommendations will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Guess you need to show some code. There is more than one way to do what you say you are doing, so nobody can help without really knowing the problem.

Comment: @calas: Thanks, added the code to the description.